# Constrained linear matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-matrix-inequality

Consider the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$ A - \delta B^{\text{T}} B > 0 \tag{1} \label{1} $$

where $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ is a known symmetric positive definite matrix, $ B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ is also known, and $ \delta \in \mathbb{R} > 0 $ is unknown. Further, let

$$ \| B x \|^2 < \frac{1}{\delta} \tag{2} \label{2} $$

be a bound on $Bx$ where $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $. The goal is to maximize $\delta$ such that the bound in \eqref{2} is minimized while ensuring the inequality in \eqref{1} is satisfied.

LMIs are not something I have a ton of experience with and I have a couple of questions.

---

**Question 1**

If $ B^{\text{T}} B $ is invertible, then we can write (1) as;

$$
A (B^{\text{T}} B)^{-1} > \delta I_n \tag{3} \label{3}
$$

can I select
$$ 
\delta < \lambda_{\min}\big(A (B^{\text{T}} B)^{-1} \big) 
$$

to satisfy \eqref{3}? If so, is there a better way to select $ \delta $?

---

**Question 2**

Lets say  $ B^{\text{T}} B $ is not invertible. Can I still solve for $ \delta $? I am completely lost on how to approach this case.

Comment: I do not understand $ \| B x \|^2 < \frac{1}{\delta} $

Comment: $\delta$ is not a great name for a variable

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: Rodrigo,  this comes from a performance index for a control system. Eqn. (1) is needed to ensure stability and eqn (2) is needed to satisfy $H_2$ criterion. Essentially, (2) is a bound on the energy of the output of the system. I have simplified the expressions quite a bit to make this post more readable; however, there is no loss in generality since an appropriate choice for $A$ will yield the original expression.

Comment: Please append a motivation section including such information. Comments are ephemeral